# Android shared drawing canvas path drawing order

Tags: android, firebase, canvas, firebase-realtime-database, path

I am developing a collaborative art app in which users can draw on a canvas together form a distance using the FireBase real time database. I have got to the point where the segment drawn on one user screen appears on the screen of the other user and vise versa.

However, once the segment is pulled from firebase, it draws the segment in the background in stead of on top of the "paint" from the user.

Is there a way to tell the program to always draw the different segments on top of each other?

[The orange line drawn on the right phone appears in the background of the left phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hydls.png)

I have put the pieces of code I use here:

This is where I pull the segment from FireBase:

```
        mListener=mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                String name=dataSnapshot.getKey();
                if (!mOutstandingSegments.contains(name)) {
                    Segment segment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Segment.class);

                    drawSegmentPath(segment.getPoints(), segment.getColor(), segment.getBlurEnabled(), segment.getStrokeWidth());

                    //invalidate();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {            
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

The segment is converted to a path with this method:

```
    public void drawSegmentPath(List<Point> segmentPoints, int color, boolean blurEnabled, float strokeWidth){
        Point currentSegmentPoint = segmentPoints.get(0);

        Path newSegmentPath = new Path();
        FingerPath fireBasePath = new FingerPath(color, blurEnabled, strokeWidth, newSegmentPath);

        firePath.add(fireBasePath);

        newSegmentPath.reset();

        newSegmentPath.moveTo(currentSegmentPoint.x, currentSegmentPoint.y);

        Point nextSegmentPoint = null;
        invalidate();

        for (int i = 1; i < segmentPoints.size(); i++) {
            nextSegmentPoint = segmentPoints.get(i);
            newSegmentPath.quadTo(currentSegmentPoint.x, currentSegmentPoint.y, (int)((nextSegmentPoint.x + currentSegmentPoint.x) / 2), (int)((nextSegmentPoint.y + currentSegmentPoint.y) / 2));
            currentSegmentPoint = nextSegmentPoint;
            System.out.println("Current Segment Points: " + currentSegmentPoint);

            invalidate();
        }


        if (nextSegmentPoint != null) {
            newSegmentPath.lineTo(nextSegmentPoint.x, nextSegmentPoint.y);
            invalidate();
        }

    }
```

Then in onDraw(), the path is drawn on the same canvas (mCanvas) as the lines the user draws on its own phone:

```
    @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            canvas.save();
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            for(FingerPath fireBasePath : firePath){
                mPaint.setColor(fireBasePath.myColor);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fireBasePath.strokeWidth);
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

                if (fireBasePath.blurEnabled){testPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);}

                mCanvas.drawPath(fireBasePath.path, mPaint);
            }

            for(FingerPath fp : paths){
                mPaint.setColor(fp.myColor);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

                if (fp.blurEnabled){mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);}

                mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);

            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, drawMatrix, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.concat(drawMatrix);
            canvas.restore();
            invalidate();

    }
```

A segment is being made when the user moves its finger over the screen by constantly adding points in the Segment class:

```
    pivate void touchStart(float positionX, float positionY){

        mPath = new Path();
        FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentBrushColor, blurEnabled, strokeWidth, mPath);
        mCurrentSegment = new Segment(currentBrushColor, strokeWidth, blurEnabled);
        paths.add(fp);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(positionX, positionY);

        mX = positionX;
        mY = positionY;

        mCurrentSegment.addPoint((int)mX, (int)mY);

    }

    private void touchMove(float positionX, float positionY){
        float dx = Math.abs(positionX - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(positionY - mY);

        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE){
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (positionX + mX)/2, (positionY + mY)/2);
            mX = positionX;
            mY = positionY;
            mCurrentSegment.addPoint((int)mX, (int)mY);
        }
    }
```

Then when the user is done drawing, the segment is pushed into FireBase:

```
    private void touchUp(){
        mPath.lineTo(mX,mY);

        DatabaseReference segmentRef=mRef.push();
        final String segmentName=segmentRef.getKey();
        currentSegmentKey=segmentName;
        mOutstandingSegments.add(segmentName);

        Segment mySegment = new Segment(mCurrentSegment.getColor(), mCurrentSegment.getStrokeWidth(), blurEnabled);
        for (Point point: mCurrentSegment.getPoints()) {
            mySegment.addPoint(point.x , point.y );
        }

        System.out.println("Segment is: " + mySegment);

        // Save our segment into Firebase.
        segmentRef.setValue(mySegment, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference firebaseRef) {
                if (error != null) {
                    throw error.toException();
                }
                mOutstandingSegments.remove(segmentName);
            }
        });
    }
```

The different onTouch methods are called in the following onTouchEvent lstener:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

            float positionX = event.getX()
            float positionY = event.getY()

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touchStart(positionX, positionY);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touchMove(positionX, positionY);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touchUp();
                    invalidate();

                    break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger. You've posted over 450 lines of code, which is way too much for us to reasonably help with. I suggest you work on isolating the problem following the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank @FrankvanPuffelen for your reply! please forgive me. I have just a few weeks of coding experience and this is my first post, so in my mind, everything is important, haha. I have tried to structure the code to make it more understandable and got rid of unnecessary stuff ;) Hope this makes it more understandable!